# Spacing Navbar To The Right

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hi I am wondering how to move my navbar contents to the right. So far by default they are to the left.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since bootstrap4 use flexbox, you can use `justify-content-end` class to align items at right:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light justify-content-end">
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#">About<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
   <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Another option is adding `margin-left:auto` (ml-auto) to both your `button` and `ul class="navbar-nav"` as following:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
 <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#">About<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
   <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: See demo in "Full page" and resize your browser window to see all links...

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" style="text-align: right;">
   ...
</nav>
```

Comment: Tried it but it does nothing to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have many possibilities.

```
.navbar { float: right;} 
or
.navbar { text-align: right;}
```

Here is 2 solutions :
[JsFiddle - align navbar to the right](https://jsfiddle.net/7g9x1of5/2/)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.ml-auto`

like this

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
```

[Play here](https://www.bootply.com/g5862uXIrG)

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar-collapse{
 justify-content: flex-end
}
```

or can use this

`.navbar-collapse{
     direction: rtl;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
.navbar{ text-align:right;}
```